# If $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $(x_0,y_0)$, then there is a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f(x,y)>\frac12f(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The exercise asks me to prove 2 things:

1) $f(x,y) $ is continuous in $(x_0,y_0)$, $f(x_0,y_0)>0$ then there is a neighborhood such that $f(x,y)>\frac{1}{2}f(x_0,y_0)$

My idea:

$f$ is continuous, then $|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|< \delta\implies |f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|< \epsilon \implies f(x_0,y_0) -\epsilon <f(x,y) < f(x_0,y_0) + \epsilon$. It's true for all $\epsilon$, so if I choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}f(x_0,y_0)$
we have:

$$\frac{1}{2}f(x_0,y_0)<f(x,y) < f(x_0,y_0) + \frac{1}{2}f(x_0,y_0)$$

2) Suppose $f$ is continuous in a domain $D$. Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is positive for at least $1$ point of $D$ and negative for at least one point of D. Then $f(x,y) = 0$ for at least one point of $D$. (suggestion: use $1$)

How to use $1$ to prove $2$? As I know, this can be understood as the mean value theorem for multivariables, but I couldn't find a proof that used $1$.

Comment: Are you sure the statement is true? $f(x,y)=-(x^2+y^2)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ but there is no neighborhood of $(0,0)$ such that $f(x,y)>\frac{1}{2}f(0,0)=0$

Comment: 1) is not necessarily true if $f(x_0,y_0)\le0$.

Comment: @user2017059 yes, sorry, there is also this condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding the second question.**

By definition, the domain $D$ is an open connected subset.

Consider $U_+ = \{(x,y) \in D | f(x,y) > 0\}$ and $U_- = \{(x,y) \in D | f(x,y) < 0\}$.

By question 1, $U_+$ and $U_-$ are neighborhood of all their elements and therefore open subsets of $D$. Another argument is that they are the inverse images of the open subsets of $\mathbb R$: $(-\infty , 0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$

If $f$ doesn't vanish then $D$ is the union of the two non intersecting open subsets $U_+, U_-$ in contradiction with the fact that $D$ is connected. Hence, $f$ vanishes.

Comment: This is insufficient, since the domain is not convex. And does not use 1.

Comment: @scineram Another proof valid when $D$ is not convex.

Comment: And your original idea can be adapted to the non-convex case by using that a [connected open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_Open_Subset_of_Euclidean_Space_is_Path-Connected).  That doesn't use part (1) from the OP, though.